# Which one is better O(V+E) or O(ElogE)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, graph-theory, breadth-first-search, kruskals-algorithm

I am trying to develop an algorithm which will be able to find minimum spanning tree from a graph.I know there are already many existing algorithms for it.However I am trying to eliminate the sorting of edges required in Kruskal's Algorithm.The algorithm I have developed so far has a part where counting of disjoint sets is needed and I need a efficient method for it.After a lot of study I came to know that the only possible way is using BFS or DFS which has a complexity of O(V+E) whereas Kruskal's algorithms has a complexity of O(ElogE).Now my question is which one is better,O(V+E) or O(ElogE)?

Comment: Assuming there are no cycles, `V` can be expressed in terms of `E`, using Euler's formula. Therefore `O(V+E)` is actually just `O(E)`. Since `O(n) < O(nlogn)`, `O(E + V) ~= O(E) < O(ElogE) `. I'm not sure about my math so posting this as a comment and not an answer

Comment: @Srini You can't assume there is no cycle since the question is about computing the minimum spanning tree of a graph (so undirected and with potentially non-trivial cycles). However, assuming there is a tree to find we can safely assume that `V <= E`

Comment: @Rerito good point, I disregarded the cycles aspect because I was not sure how to deal with the `F` component of `V - E + F = 2` for Euler's formula for planar graphs. But I suppose if the OP or someone else could figure out how to deal with that or prove that `V` still shares a linear relationship w.r.t `E` then I guess they could still build on this argument

Comment: Running both algorithms in parallel and stopping as soon as one finishes gives you the complexity `O(min(V+E, E Log E))`, which is always the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, `E = O(V^2)`, but that bound may not be tight for all graphs. In particular, in a sparse graph, `E = O(V)`, but for an algorithm complexity is usually stated as a worst-case value.

`O(V + E)` is a way of indicating that the complexity depends on how many edges there are. In a sparse graph, `O(V + E) = O(V + V) = O(V)`, while in a dense graph `O(V + E) = O(V + V^2) = O(V^2)`.

Another way of looking at it is to see that in big-O notation, `O(X + Y)` means the same thing as `O(max(X, Y))`.

Note that this is only useful when `V` and `E` might have the same magnitude. For Kruskal's algorithm, the dominating factor is that you need to sort the list of edges. Whether you have a sparse graph or a dense graph, that step dominates anything that might be `O(V)`, so one simply writes `O(E lg E)` instead of `O(V + E lg E)`.

Comment: Could you please give an idea about the O(ElogE)?

Comment: Kruskal's algorithm involves sorting the edge list, so whether you have a sparse or dense graph, that will dominate the cost of simply iterating over an unordered list. The "additive" term `V` is irrelevant in either case, so one just writes `O(E lg E)` rather than `O(V + E lg E)`.